# Pandas - Can read list of MultiIndex but cannot set them

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have two DataFrames, both have the same multi-index with the same levels (a code and a date). The first one contains every row where there was data (from database extract) and the second one is the same DataFrame, except it contains all the keys (every month of the horizon for every product).

To make it a bit more clear, here is the first dataframe (`df_data`):

```
                               BL0   BL1   BL2   BL3  Shipments
Code             Month
ABC              2012-03-01   1000  1000  1000  1000       1000
DEF              2014-08-01   1000  1000  1000  1000       1000
                 2014-09-01   1000  1000  1000  1000       1000
GHI              2013-12-01   1000  1000  1000  1000       1000
                 2014-10-01   1000  1000  1000  1000       1000
                 2014-12-01   1000  1000  1000  1000       1000
```

And here is the second one (`df_full`), with all the month from Jan 2012 to Jan 2015:

```
                               BL0   BL1   BL2   BL3  Shipments
Code             Month
ABC              2012-01-01    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN        NaN
                 2012-02-01    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN        NaN
                 2012-03-01   1000  1000  1000  1000       1000
                 2012-04-01    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN        NaN
                 ...
DEF              2014-07-01    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN        NaN
                 2014-08-01   1000  1000  1000  1000       1000
                 2014-09-01   1000  1000  1000  1000       1000
                 2014-10-01    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN        NaN
                 ...
GHI              2013-12-01   1000  1000  1000  1000       1000
                 2014-10-01   1000  1000  1000  1000       1000
                 2014-12-01   1000  1000  1000  1000       1000
```

Right now, I have the first one and I am trying to build the second one. I created an empty DataFrame with the MultiIndex, created each column filled with NaNs and I am stuck on setting the values of `df_full` to what they are in `df_data`.

When I do

```
df_full.loc[ df_data.index, 'Shipments' ] = df_data['Shipments']
```

I get an error saying that the index of `df_data` isn't in `df_dull`:

```
KeyError: "[('ABC', '2012-03-01') ('DEF', '2014-08-01')\n ('DEF', '2014-09-01') ...,  
('XYZ', '2014-11-01')\n ('XYZ', '2014-12-01')] not in index"
```

What bugs me is that if I just do `df_full.loc[ data.index, 'Shipments' ]` it returns the Series without any problem. I tried using a list of tuples instead of an Index, and I also tried setting the slice to 1, but to no avail.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The index in `KeyError` looks odd. A `\n` in there? Or is that an artefact from printing the output?

Comment: Also, what is `data.index` ? You mention a `df_data` and `df_full` only.

Comment: `data.index` is `df_data.index`, I edited the question to correct this. The `\n` is probably linked to the fact that this level of index was strings instead of datetime, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, the problem turned out to lie in the fact that the two DataFrame's indexes were not of the same type.

- `df_data`'s index was a (string, string), and pandas didn't recognize that the seconde was a date when reading the csv source file and I didn't convert to datetime.
- `df_full`'s index was (string, pandas.Timestamp), and the second term happened to be formatted into exactly the same string as `df_data`, hence my confusion.

When given a date-like string, pandas can understand and find the right row, but it seems like it can't find it when I was trying to assign a value to it.

After converting `df_data`'s index to (string, pandas.Timestamp), everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to construct all possible combinations of commodities and days, you can use a nice built in iterable, `MultiIndex.from_product`.

```
commodities=['ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL']
days=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2012',end='1/1/2015',freq='D')
columns = ['BL0', 'BL1','BL2', 'BL3','Shipments']
indx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([commodities,days])
output = pd.DataFrame(index=indx,columns=columns)
output.head()


                BL0  BL1  BL2  BL3 Shipments
ABC 2012-01-01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
    2012-01-02  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
    2012-01-03  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
    2012-01-04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
    2012-01-05  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
```

Then you can replace actual values as appropriate given the levels of the multi-indices.